# Bootstrap - footer still at the end of page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

I want to have a footer still at the end of the page.

Teoretically, it's working, but if I shrink the width of browser, the footer will go a little bit higher from the real end of the page.

That means, that I have some free background space under the footer - I don't want that.

Fullscreen of my page - no problem with footer
[image: Fullscreen of my page - no problem with footer]

Shrinked page almost to half - problem with footer
[image: Shrinked page almost to half - problem with footer]

Mobile shrinked - no problem
[image: Mobile shrinked - no problem]

Here is the html code:

```css
body 
{
    background-color: black; 
}

.navbar 
{
    background-color: black;
}

.nav-pills .active
{
    /*  FARBA AKTÍVNEHO TABU V NAVIGÁCII A JEHO ZAOBLENIE */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%);
    border-radius: 2%;
}

.row.first-row {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 4em;
    margin-left: 4em;
}
h4.white 
{
    color: white;
}

#tl
/* TLAČIDLÁ "What I will learn?" */
{
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

/* info SÚ INFORMÁCIE O AUTOROVI V BIELOM PÁSE */
.info 
{
    margin-top: 3em;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.info p 
{
    padding-top: 0.2em;
}

footer 
{
    
}



@media screen and (max-width: 768px) 
{
    div.col-md-4
    {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CONFT</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style_index.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo_tab_icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <script>
        $(function () 
        {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:50px;">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About author</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="CCNA 3" 
                    data-content="This course is already in progress. Stay tuned.">CCNA 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="images/gradient_bg.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1 class="display-1">Welcome to CONFT</h1>
                    <p>Drill your knowledge on your way to get CCNA certification.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/abstract_network.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1 class="display-2">Your job is on demand</h1>
                    <p>Networking field still need more and more skilled people. Join them!</p>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="images/programming.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h1 class="display-2">Programming in networking</h1>
                    <p>If you know programming, you can apply a job in this field too - because of need of automation.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="row first-row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="border-radius: 5px; background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%">
                <h1 class="text-center display-4 text-white" style="color: black;">CCNA 1</h1>
                <h4 class="white text-center">Introduction to Networks</h4>
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" id="tl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">What will I learn?</button>
    
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                    
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">CCNA 1 v7.0</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>The first course in the CCNA curriculum introduces the architectures, models, protocols, and networking elements that connect users,
                                    devices, applications and data through the Internet and across modern computer networks – including IP addressing and Ethernet fundamentals.
                                </p>
                                <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#" role="button">Start learning now!</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="border-radius: 5px; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%">
                <h1 class="text-center display-4 text-white" style="color: black;">CCNA 2</h1>
                <h4 class="white text-center">Switching, Routing, and Wireless Essentials</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" id="tl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">What will I learn?</button>
    
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                    
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">CCNA 2 v7.0</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>The second course in the CCNA curriculum focuses on switching technologies and router operations that support small-to-medium business networks
                                    and includes wireless local area networks (WLAN) and security concepts. Students learn key switching and routing concepts. 
                                    They can perform basic network configuration and troubleshooting, identify and mitigate LAN security threats, and configure and secure a basic WLAN.
                                </p>
                                <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#" role="button">Start learning now!</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="border-radius: 5px; background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%">
                <h1 class="text-center display-4 text-white" style="color: black;">CCNA 3</h1>
                <h4 class="white text-center">Enterprise Networking and Security</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" id="tl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">What will I learn?</button>
    
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal3" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                    
                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">CCNA 3 v7.0</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>The third course in the CCNA curriculum describes the architectures and considerations related to designing, securing, operating, 
                                    and troubleshooting enterprise networks. This course covers wide area network (WAN) technologies and quality of service (QoS) mechanisms 
                                    used for secure remote access along with the introduction of software-defined networking, virtualization, and automation concepts
                                    that support the digitalization of networks. Students gain skills to configure and troubleshoot enterprise networks, 
                                    and learn to identify and protect against cybersecurity threats. They are introduced to network management tools 
                                    and learn key concepts of software-defined networking, including controller-based architectures and how 
                                    application programming interfaces (APIs) enable network automation.
                                </p>
                                <a class="btn btn-dark" href="#" role="button">Start learning now!</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center info" style="background-color: white;">
        <p>Hi! I'm René the creator of this site. I appreciate you visit my site. If you want to know more about me, <a href="#">click here</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <footer class="bg-primary text-white text-center text-lg-start">
        <!-- Copyright -->
        <div class="text-center p-3" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffbb59 0%, #ff654d 100%">
            © 2021 Copyright: René Martin Kuda, SPŠT Spišská Nová Ves, 3.D
        </div>
        <!-- Copyright -->
      </footer>
      

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as long as your webpage ends with this text only so the footer is at the end of your page, but if u add couple of line breaks `<br><br>` your footer will go to the end then and will be shown as you need exactly, and add to your footer CSS style `bottom: 0px;` so the footer will be at the bottom of your page.
hope it helps you

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman, It is not good advice to use `<br>` to close gaps. And to use `bottom: 0px;`, the `footer` must be absolutely positioned.

Comment: guys thx! I've used media querie --> 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) 
{
    footer 
    {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }    
}
and in normal css I used footer margin-top: 130px